# Работа Android Studio в Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, поиск-программ

Слышал что в операционной системе Linux удобно работать в Android Studio. А какой дистрибутив поставить, чтобы было легче работать на Android?

Компьютер:

- Видеокарта 1 ГБ.
- Оперативная память 2 ГБ.
- Процессор Intel Celeron 2.8 ГГц.

Comment: Чтобы худо-бедно работать в Android Studio понадобится хотя бы 16 Гб оперативки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Вам, можно поставить любой из популярных дистрибутивов (Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Debian), а если компьютер имеет "слабые" параметры, то стоит задуматься о правильном выборе окружения рабочего стола(Unity, KDE, Gnome, Cinnamon и т.д.) если параметры видео довольно слабые то ваш выбор - любой из минималистичных окружений. По данной ссылке вы найдете Linux Mint с выбором окружения https://www.linuxmint.com/download.php .
Советую Cinnamon или XFCE.

Comment: Видеокарта 1ГБ. Оперативная память 2ГБ. Процессор Intel Celeron 2.8 ГГц.

Comment: Вам отлично подойдет Cinnamon, тем более если раньше вы работали в окнах.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Не понял вопрос.

Comment: @akmaltilloev а зачем, если не секрет?

Comment: @akmaltilloev задавайте вопросы на stack'е вам ответят, в том числе и я

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64007/discussion-between-akmaltilloev-and-n-turshiev).

Comment: @N. Turshiev лучше Mint Xfce Edition - он менее требователен, а выглядит не хуже